# when i access my MVC site it works great but when i access same with domain name it ask for authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

i am working on a site which is working great at my space 
but when i put it on hosting server and access it **with domain name**. It ask me for authentication at some pages.

**at the same when i access this with ip address it works fine..**

Screenshot

[image]

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share snapshots?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/lgir0xmrr/  This is the snapshot plz check it

Comment: @JAYRAJPUROHIT you can delete your comment if you want. i have edited your question and uploaded image in your post.

Comment: Check your webserver configuration. Ensure that Anonymous Authentication is enabled and you don't have any incorrect ACLs set in your filesystem.

Comment: Might not be directly related to the problem, but did you map the  the domain name to ip in your hosts file or did you specify it in a DNS server?